# Hibernate does not qualify attribute called 'end'

Tags: java, hibernate

We are trying to upgrade our application from Hibernate 3.2.6 to Hibernate 3.5.6.

We have some classes with columns called 'start' and 'end'. For example:

```
@Column(name='start')
public Date getStart() {
 return this.start;
}

@Column(name='end')
public Date getEnd() {
 return this.end;
}
```

When Hibernate produces a SQL for example to load a object,  it never qualify the 'end' attribute producing errors in case of joins between tables with the same named attribute. For example, Hibernate produces something like this:

```
select user.start, end from user ...
```

At this moment, we would need a solution without changing the name of the attribute.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: With Hibernate you can write your own native sql queries. Try to do that for the few queries you have problems with

Comment: What is your underlying database?  My first impulse is to say that `END` is a reserved keyword in many RDBMS like MySQL.

Comment: What is the code causing this query to be executed? Why are you migrating from a completely obsolete version to another obsolete version of Hibernate? Hibernate is at version 5.0. The version you're migrating to is 5 years old.

Comment: also try to add property hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the underlying DBMS, you might be able to escape the name of the column, i.e. `@Column(name="\"end\"")`.

I have no idea why Hibernate's behaviour would have changed between versions, though.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/
Examples with solutions

Comment: Thank you very much. You put me in the right way. Double quotes is the solution, but in that case where I have a lot of entities from a lot of modules out of my own control, we do prefer a generic solution, so following your idea I wrote a Custom Naming Strategy to rename all columns named "end" into "\"end\"". 

Than you again.

Comment: But unfortunatelly this solution is parcial because when hibernate produces an update sentence it does also with double quotes producing something like this:

`code`
update user set "end"=? where id=?
`code`

And this produces a Sintax Error in Informix.

Comment: Informix is quite far from the standard there. The `DELIMIDENT` setting seems to allow escaping identifiers in double quotes there, too: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1614.htm

Comment: Thank you very much Henning, but stablishing now the DELIMIDENT environment variables is not a viable solution for me due to the amount of SQL sentencias written yet of the project , that is very big. I Cannot asume there are not SQL written usen double quotes to delimit literales.